# How to paste over a selection in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Most other editors I'm used to will overwrite selected text, and I'd like to configure Visual Studio Code to do this if possible.

The current behavior seems to be: `foo` is selected, `bar` is on the clipboard -> I invoke paste. The result in the editor is `foobar`.

What I would like: `foo` is selected, `bar` is on the clipboard -> I invoke paste. The result in the editor is `bar`.

Is this possible, with or without an extension?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Does it still happen if you restart vscode with all extensions disabled?  `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled`.

Comment: Another thing to look at: how are you invoking `paste`?  You can check to see what vscode interprets the paste keybinding as with `Developer:  Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting`.

Comment: Interesting, it looks like it is being intercepted by an emacs extension I have: `From 2 keybinding entries, matched emacs.C-y, when: editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly, source: user extension lfs.vscode-emacs-friendly.` What I can't tell from this is if it is mapping the past functionality to something in vs code, or if it is implementing its own way of pasting.

Comment: I see this in the repo: https://github.com/SebastianZaha/vscode-emacs-friendly/pull/74 Looks like there are some issues with pasting not over-writing correctly.

Comment: Well, just for those coming here looking for something that may work better, I'm having a decent experience with "Awesome Emacs Keymap (emacs-mcx)" - and it works in the newly released vscode.dev (vscode in a browser), unlike most other emacs extensions